# Weird behaviour with tweepy in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.9 on OS X (10.11). I have installed tweepy 3.5.0 and simplejson 3.8.1. When i write a program (IDE: textWrangler) for updating status of twitter account (by using tweepy) and run the program using command line it throws error on "import tweepy" in a program. However when i run the same code on python shell, it execute sucessfuly (without any error). Any suggestions or comments?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweepytesting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ssl_match_hostname
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError, match_hostname
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 90, in <module>
    import textwrap
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TextWrapper:
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
    whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

If I add this line:

```
import string; print(string)
```

just above `import tweepy`, then the following is printed:

```
<module 'string' from '/Users/yasirmuhammad/Desktop/learnpython/string.pyc'>
```

Comment: What's the error? Where's your code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini The error is on the first line of the program. The first line of the program is "import tweepy" and the error is "Traceback (most recent call last): File "tweepytesting.py", line 1, in <module> import tweepy "

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full traceback (you left out the most important part)

Comment: Do you have a file named `string.py` somewhere?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini no i don't have any file name string.py

Comment: Above `import tweepy`, please write this: `import string; print(string)`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini i wrote the above mentioned code by you in my program. Still error points on the import tweepy (as it was before adding code). However, print (string) produce this statement: "<module 'string' from '/Users/yasirmuhammad/Desktop/learnpython/string.pyc'>"

Comment: That file (`string.pyc`) is what causes the problem. Remove it. If you also have a file named `string.py`, then remove it or rename it.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini i deleted above mentioned both files but still the same output :(

Comment: If `print(string)` still prints that line, it means that the file still exist. Python cannot "invent" files :)